# How does python know where to look for a file if you passed it as an argument?

Tags: python, filepath

I am curious to know how python knows where to find the file you passed to a function/method. For example, I am reading csv files and in the shell environment I stated:

```
python3 readcsv.py test.csv
```

I'm guessing python assumes that you wrote ./test.csv (meaning current directory) so it looks for your file in the current directory. If that's the case does python not have a default search path where it looks for files normally or do you have to explicitly say where to find your files passed as arguments?

Comment: This has nothing to do with python, that's just how unix works. And you aren't passing it to a function, you're passing it to a *python program*, invoked by the shell.

Comment: After I wrote that question I realized that the shell evaluates your command, and then, includes your relative path and passes it to the program. So even though this isn't  a python question, It would be interesting to know how python parses that relative path. Something I'll look into.

Comment: If you pass a string like `test.csv` to a Python script to indicate a file, it is up to the script where it looks for the file. If the script just tries to use it as a file path, it will mean a file with that name in the current working directory. It won't go looking in other possible places for it.

Comment: @khelwood ok so your response here makes the most sense to me. When in python you write open(file) I'm guessing this is where your sys.argv "file path" goes. Then it looks for the file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an argument `test.csv` to a script, it's just a string. Same as if you pass `hello` or `45` or `-f`. How the string is interpreted is up to the script.

The script *could* look in some particular directories for a matching file, if the programmer wrote it that way. But that is not a default behaviour.

If the Python script treats the string as file path and tries something like

```
 filename = sys.argv[1]
 ...
 f = open(filename)
```

to read the file, then it will look for a file with the given name in the current working directory, and nowhere else. If you wanted to look somewhere else, you would need to pass the file's path into the script instead of just the name.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with python. This is how arguments work when you pass them to a program

For example

In python you can read them like this (sys.argv is a list)

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv)

# prints ['readcsv.py', 'test.csv']
```

In C

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("\"%s\", ", *(i + argv));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Or in shell

sh

```sh
#! /bin/sh

echo $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to explicitly say where to find the files passed as arguments. It's the same for all languages when passing a file to a script.

Except if the programer that wrote the script wrote an exception in the script to look for the files specified beyond the path you gave it to look for.